# zero of second order

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm studying functions associated with a domain in the complex plane. In one paper that I'm reading, a particular function, $R(a, b)$, is discussed (with "$a$" varying and "$b$" fixed complex variables) and it is reported that at the point "$b = a$" in the complex plane, where this function is zero, the "zero of $R$ is second order" (quote directly from the paper). I am trying to work out precisely what this last statement means.

Can you give me any suggestions about what statement this may refer to?

Comment: Can mean that you have a double root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you have a function $f$ given by the expansion $f(z) = a_2 (z-b)^2 + a_3 (z-b)^3 + \cdots$, then it is clear that $f$ has a zero at $b$. The order of the zero is then the exponent of the first appearing term. In the case of what I wrote, it's $2$.

Having a high order zero means that the function vanishes very quickly at that point. This begins to matter in complex analysis especially when considering using residue theorems and analyzing behaviour of poles, as poles and zeroes partially cancel each other.

Comment: Thank you. That helped - I verified using a Taylor expansion that my function does have a zero of second order as per your definition of the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

A complex function $f(z)$ is said to have a zero at $z=a$ of order $n$ if $f(a)=f'(a)=f''(a)=.....=f^{n-1}(a)=0$ and $f^{n}(a)\neq 0$.